# Randomly get row where field is not, mysql

Tags: mysql, random, filter

I'm trying to get a single row from a mysql-database using one of the advanced random-functions that exist out there. However, when I try to filter to only get rows rows that has "field = 1" in them, everything fails. Can somebody please spot my error?

```
SELECT username, message, ttime 
FROM table WHERE done LIKE '1' AS r1 JOIN 
   (SELECT (RAND() *
                 (SELECT MAX(id)
                    FROM database)) AS id)
    AS r2
WHERE r1.id >= r2.id
ORDER BY r1.id ASC
LIMIT 1;";
```

Comment: Why do you need an "advanced random function"?

Comment: I'm trying to get a random row from a huge database, using the traditional code is way to slow. In addition, this supposedly eliminiates problems with deleted rows.

Comment: Many tables have an auto-incrementing integer primary key. When a row is deleted, the `holes` that occur do not get filled in, they just stay.  Testing on `r1.id >= r2.id` instead of `r1.id = r2.id` fixes the problem that you might hit a hole (at a slight performance cost)

Comment: ...and some bias in the result probabilities.  (Rows that follow a deleted row have a higher chance of being selected.)

Answer (score 1):

The query you have in your question has multiple syntax errors.
Did you want something like this?

```
SELECT username, message, ttime 
FROM database.table1 as r1 
INNER JOIN 
   (SELECT (RAND() * MAX(id)) as a_random_id
    FROM database.table1) r2
ON (r1.id >= r2.a_random_id)
WHERE done = '1'
ORDER BY r1.id ASC
LIMIT 1
```

I wonder if this variant is faster:

```
SELECT r.username, r.message, r.ttime 
FROM database.table1 r 
WHERE r.id = (  
  SELECT MIN(r1.id)  <<-- this should make MySQL stop after the first hit.
  FROM database.table1 r1 
  INNER JOIN 
     (SELECT (RAND() * MAX(id)) as a_random_id
      FROM database.table1) AS r2
  ON (r1.id >= r2.a_random_id)
  WHERE r1.done = '1') sub
```

Oh and you don't select from a `database`, you select from a **`table`** inside a database.

Comment: That works, but it applies the "WHERE done" after the randomization has been done, making it a possibility that a row is discarded after being selected. Would it be possible to apply this filtering before selecting rows or making the system take another "turn" if the end result is discarding the row?